# Issue in preg_match function (return null values when var_dump)

Tags: php, regex

actually working on ubuntu, with PhpStorm, I'm trying (slowly but surely) to use regex to extract text from a .txt file.

For example, i'm looking to get a GSM number with this regex :

```
$pattern_numGSM = '#(GSM : (.{10}))#i';
```

To test it, I use this piece of code :

```
$subject = $fichier_noExt.'.txt';
preg_match($pattern_numGSM, $subject, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
var_dump($matches[1]);
var_dump($matches[2]);
```

Having $fichier_noExt my txt file, which I can't share with you due to rights agreements... (It a bill for a phone buy, containing informations that i need to extract, like : [bill_example](http://images.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.compta-entrepreneurs.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2009%2F03%2Ffacture_ae.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.compta-entrepreneurs.com%2Fmes-logiciels%2Fnouveaux-modeles-de-factures-pour-les-auto-entrepreneur%2F&h=600&w=421&tbnid=7VDrun0s9wSNwM%3A&docid=zr44wJyn42KIuM&ei=IHoHWIu6GseqafLav4gH&tbm=isch&client=ubuntu&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=636&page=0&start=0&ndsp=46&ved=0ahUKEwiLyoW6gefPAhVHVRoKHXLtD3EQMwg3KAQwBA&bih=951&biw=1855))

Doing this, i get on my localhost the values : 
null
null
null

I checked the veracity of my regex on the web, it works fine but asa I test it back on phpstorm, null is all I got...

I've been stuck on it for half a day, so if your fresh eyes see anything that I miss, would be nice :).

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Stelio Kontos.

**EDIT : Problem solved, I was preg_matching my file, and not the content of my file... Yep, feeling so smart right now :d.
Thanks Patrick !**

Comment: Firstly, your example is so low-res as to be unreadable. Second, what text are you actually trying to match (anonymize it if it contains confidential information)?

Comment: You're running your regex against the file name, not the contents of the file.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz I know it's unreadable, it was just so you can see the structure of my document. On my side, i'm working with good res files.

Here an example of text i'm reading into :

[code]Facture No : 30

le : 04-10-2016

Designation

TELEPHONE SONY SONY XPERIA E5 BLANC
No Série Qté

359666072097244 1

Prix

Remise Mont TTC

59,90

59,90

Forfait : US illimité SMS/MMS 5 Go/SL UE 24 M. Opérateur : NRJ Mobile. No SIM :
8933260200123945912F. Durée : 24 Mois. No GSM : 0771837124.[/code]